# Why does this approach for adding dynamic rows in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC appear to be returning JSON in my Razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-7.0

I'm trying to get a few different textboxes to output dynamically.  Following the pattern for adding rows dynamically in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC found [here](https://github.com/stevcooo/AddItemsDynamically), I was able to implement this into a small basic project and felt like I had a pretty good grasp on his approach to adding rows dynamically.

However I'm having trouble trying to put this same approach into a larger project (also .NET 7) that is using view models and DTOs. My current efforts are just yielding what looks to be JSON of the DTO.

Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong or if I'm missing something else in trying to implement this approach into a more complicated project?  Ultimately I'm trying to create dynamic rows for a fairly straight forward ordering system using as little Javascript as possible. Most of the approaches I've seen only show using basic models.

Some of my code is below:

Current output being displayed in the Razor view looks as such:

```
PurchaseOrderLineItemDto { PurchaseOrderLineItemId = 0, LineItemNumber = 0, LineItemDescription = , LineItemQuantity = 0, LineItemUnitPrice = 0, LineItemExtPrice = 0 }
```

View

```
@model MvcApplication.ViewModels.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create new Order";
}

      <div class="row">
        <div class="container pt-4 table-responsesive text-nowrap" id="orderItemsContainer">
          <table class="table table-borderless" id="tblPurchaseOrderLineItems">
                        <thead>
                            @foreach (var orderLineItem in Model.PurchaseOrderLineItems)
                            {
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => orderLineItem.LineItemDescription)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => orderLineItem.LineItemQuantity)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => orderLineItem.LineItemUnitPrice)
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => orderLineItem.LineItemExtPrice)
                            </th>
                            }
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderLineItems)
                        </tbody>
            
          </table>
```

View model class:

```
namespace MvcApplication.ViewModels.PurchaseOrders
{
    public record PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel
    {
        [DefaultValue(null)]
        public List<PurchaseOrderLineItemDto> PurchaseOrderLineItems { get; set; }

        public PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel()
        {
            PurchaseOrderLineItems = new List<PurchaseOrderLineItemDto>();
        }
    }
}
```

EditorTemplate

```
@model MvcApplication.ViewModels.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel
<tr>
    <td class="col-8">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseOrderLineItems, new {style="width: 100%", @class="form-control rounded-0", @type="text"})
    </td>
    <td>
    <td class="d-flex" style="width:20%;">
        <button class="btnDeleteLineItemRow btn btn-danger rounded-0 flex-fill" id="deleteLineItemRow"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

View for `EditorTemplate` (called by controller method to add new row)

```
@model MvcApplication.ViewModels.PurchaseOrders.PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PurchaseOrderLineItems)
```

Controller method for adding new line item:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("AddOrderItem")]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddOrderItem([Bind("PurchaseOrderLineItems")] PurchaseOrderCreateViewModel purchaseOrderCreateViewModel)
{
    purchaseOrderCreateViewModel.PurchaseOrderLineItems.Add(new PurchaseOrderLineItemDto());
    return PartialView("PurchaseOrderLineItems", purchaseOrderCreateViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Do the values of numbers fail in passing? I tested with your code and values get passed to view for template in html, could you share more complete code.

Comment: Such problem may caused by different reasons since it occurs in large complex project. Consider that you directly show the listitem and still get the model value, you can share some error message(if there is), and are there any other changes made from the sample code?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies.  I'm not getting a chance to pass any values as I don't get any of the textboxes specified in the EditorTemplate.  When I click the button in my view to add it calls the method for AddOrderItem which calls the partial view and then  just populates the page with text which is what I specified in my very first code example.  I'm also not getting any errors either.   I've included pretty much all the code need to get this EditorTemplate to work was there something specific you'd like to see?

Comment: Hi @JLudt, the using of @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PurchaseOrderLineItems) should not work as expected, since it is a list and cannot be passed correctly. Please check if  your code working correctly in easy project is the same with it in large project.